# Unable to change the position of page numbers in a LibreOffice Impress presentation

Tags: libreoffice

My page numbers are not working.  They appear in the upper left corner of each slide, but only halfway on the page.  How can I reposition the page numbers?  The obvious solution is not working:

I'm able to change the position of the page number field in the master slide, but this has no effect in Normal View.  I notice that I can insert a new page number field in the master slide, in whatever position I want, but I can' get rid of the old page number field no matter what, so I end up with two page numbers on every slide.

Answer (score 1):

I opened View -> Master -> Master Elements and unchecked the Footer box and the Slide number box.  Then, looking at View -> Slide Master, I was happy to see that the slide number field had disappeared. However, to my surprise, the slide numbers were still visible on normal view.

Back story:  The file was originally created in PowerPoint.  I opened the .pptx file in LibreOffice and saved as .odp.  I wonder if LibreOffice didn't know how to handle the .pptx slide numbers, or something else is to blame.

So I manually deleted the slide numbers, one at a time, and then proceeded to insert a new slide number field in the Slide Master.  The newly inserted numbers look good.